# How can I solve this set of linear coupled system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, systems-of-equations

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} -2k & k \\ k & -2k \end{bmatrix}$
.I have to solve this linear coupled system :
$X'' = A.X$, where $X= \begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{bmatrix}$
.Can any one help me or give me links related to this?

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix exponentiation? You can do some manipulations on the equations as well...  But, what have you tried?

Comment: Matrix exponentiation, yes I can understand it. I tried finding the eigen values of the matrix

Comment: Is your problem an initial value problem or a boundary value problem?

Comment: This is an problem I got in the class.Nothing told about Initial conditions and boundary conditions.

Comment: What does $X^n$ mean?

Comment: $X''$ means 2nd derivatives

Comment: Hi @dexterdev, do you need some more details in my answer? Is your question already answered? Please give us some feedback.

Comment: Is $k$ integer, real, positive, smaller than $1$, or complex? The formal appearance of the solution will depend on that, since we have to take square roots of $-2k\pm1$.

Comment: k can be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some thoughts to help you to solve the problem:

- Since neither intial conditions nor boundary data are specified, the solution of the problem will depend on four constants of integration since the system of differential equations is second order in $t$.
- Assuming $k$ is a constant, the ODEs are linear and with constant coefficients. This leads you many ways to solve this. For example, *Laplace transform in* $t$, exponential methods, algebraic manipulation, etc.
- Suppose you are interested in solving this problem using **exponential methods**. You may reduce first the order of the system in order to come up with an expression such that $Y' = M Y$, where $M$ is some matrix. How can you do this? Define $u_1 = x_1, u_2 = x_1'$ and $v_1 = x_2, v_2 = x_2'$ so we have:
  \begin{align}
  u_2' &= -2k  u_1 +  k  u_2  \\
  v_2' &= k u_2 - 2 k u_2  \\
  u_1' &= u_2  \\
  v_1' &= v_2 
  \end{align} which you can re-arrange in matrix form, with $Y = (u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2)$. When you find $M$, then the solution of the problem will be given by:
  $$Y(t) = e^{Mt} C,$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary vector.
- What about **Laplace transform**?. Take Laplace transform on both sides of your system to have $$s X(s) - s X_0 + X'_0 =  A \, X(s)$$ where $X(s) = \mathcal{L}_sX(t)$ and $X_0 = X(0), X'_0 = X'(0)$ (which are unknown *constants*). The equation above is indeed an *algebraic* system of equation for the vector $X(s)$, which you can easily solve (if $A-sI$ is invertible, i.e., $s$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$). Take inverse Laplace transform then to find $X(t)$ as a function of the two constants $X_0$ and $X'_0$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My professor was going through the eigen value - vector method. That is, to decouple the system and find the solutions. But I did'nt completely got it. So I would like that method to see, (ie without reducing to first order system or using laplace methods).

Comment: In that case, I don't know exactly how to proceed. Since the matrix coefficients of your system are constant, maybe trying solutions like $X(t) = e^{R t} C$ where $R$ is a matrix and $C$ is a constant vector would be helpful. This leads you to something like: $R^2 - A = 0$, then $R$ is the *squared root of the matrix* A, which is easy to compute for the $2 \times 2$ case. I'm not sure if this is legit.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I think plugging some format like $A cos(\omega t) + B sin(\omega t)$ after diagonalizing and transforming to the original coordinates will do the trick.